# what does jQuery[addClass] mean?

Tags: jquery

what does it do in code below?

```
jQuery[addClass](...);
```

is it same as jQuery.addClass() ?

Comment: to work properly your `addClass` must be either a string in quotes, or a variable called `addClass` that contains the name of a jQuery function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use dot notation or brackets notation:

```
$.show()
```

OR

```
 $['show']()
```

Similar question [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)